# When will my application be reviewed?

Tags: software-center, application-development

I submitted an app to the Ubuntu Software Centre through my apps on developer.ubuntu.com yesterday. Will my app ever be reviewed or is my apps no longer used? My app is free and I packaged it myself already so how long will the review process take? How long until it gets reviewed (it is currently pending review)?

It is a small, mathematics tool with a GUI. I built it in the Ubuntu SDK with Qt, and packaged it. It is free, and is called HCFs and LCMs.

Comment: Give some details about your apps.. What your app is all about? Some screenshots.. Direct link such that we can install it and give reviews..

Comment: I look forward to more information. I'll certainly give it a go.

Comment: What's the app called? I'll look for it on myapps.

Comment: Is it an app for Ubuntu touch (a click app) or for Ubuntu Desktop (a .deb)?

Comment: I submitted a paid but open source app and it took around a week until it was reviewed. However, my understanding is that My Apps is closed to free apps because a newer and better packaging format (Click packages) is being developed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you have sent your application to the wrong queue I'm afraid, it should have gone to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps

I'll send your application back to you.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What did I do wrong? What queue is my app in? Once I submit it to the new queue, how long does review take?

Comment: Your app was in the old queue we used for desktop apps. Resubmit using the url Dave gave you. The queue is monitored all day. It's a pretty quick turn around (hours rather than days)